# Increase the product width in Zencart CSS

Tags: css, zen-cart

I am new to zencart and learning the basics. I have installed a theme called 'pre_green'. The theme works fine but the product sizes are very small. I checked the divs holding to the products, but cant find anything related to width. When I checked the `source-code`, I saw a `style="width:33%;` is added automatically to the divs. I guess due to this My products sizes are small.

```
    <div class="centerBoxWrapper" id="featuredProducts">
    <h2 class="centerBoxHeading">Our Products</h2>
        <div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back" style="width:33%;">
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_3&amp;products_id=7">
<img src="images/chili.gif" alt="Chilli" title=" Chilli " width="100" height="67" /></a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_3&amp;products_id=7">Chilli</a><br />Rs.0</div>
        <div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back" style="width:33%;">
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_2&amp;products_id=3">
<img src="images/melon.jpg" alt="Melon" title=" Melon " width="100" height="70" />
</a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_2&amp;products_id=3">Melon</a>
<br />Rs.0</div>
        <div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back" style="width:33%;">
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_2&amp;products_id=4">
<img src="images/orange.jpg" alt="Orange" title=" Orange " width="100" height="70" />
</a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_2&amp;products_id=4">Orange</a>
<br />Rs.0</div>
    <br class="clearBoth" />

        <div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back" style="width:33%;">
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_3&amp;products_id=9">
<img src="images/potato.jpg" alt="Potato" title=" Potato " width="80" height="80" /></a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_3&amp;products_id=9">Potato</a>
<br />Rs.50</div>
        <div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back" style="width:33%;">
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_3&amp;products_id=11">
<img src="images/tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato" title=" Tomato " width="80" height="80" />
</a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_3&amp;products_id=11">Tomato</a>
<br />Rs.60</div>
        <div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back" style="width:33%;">
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_2&amp;products_id=2">
<img src="images/banana.jpg" alt="Banana" title=" Banana " width="100" height="70" />
</a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=1_2&amp;products_id=2">Banana</a><br />Rs.30</div>
    <br class="clearBoth" />
```

So I wanted to know how can I increase the size or modify the with percentage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the template? Is there any way you can edit the files yourself?

Comment: I have installed from admin panel. Yes I can edit the files

Answer (score 0):

i think there should be an option to select how many products you have to show in one line

it will automatically increase the width

if not you have to change it in some css or php file 
it would be dangerous if you dont know some coding

make a alone before doing this experiment

Answer (score 0):

The 33% you mentioned is calculated based on the settings you choose in your Admin for how you want those content-boxes to display. You've obviously got it set to show 3 columns.
The code you posted is for id="featuredProducts", so that indicates that you're referring to your Featured Products content-box, and thus the setting to control the number of columns is at Admin->Configuration->Index Listing->Featured Products Columns per Row.

But you started out asking how to change the size of your images, and seemed to blame the 33% for them being small. But the 33% is not the cause.

The images are sized according to the dimensions you specify in Admin->Configuration->Images. For example the "Image - Featured Products Width" setting. By default that's set to 100. Change that and the corresponding Height setting to suit your wishes. Keep in mind that this number only affects what the HTML tells the browser to display the image as. If you upload smaller images they will be stretched to those dimensions. If you upload hugely larger images, they will be shrunk for display, but still must download the entire images, so don't upload images larger than you intend to use else it will degrade your visitors' experience. 
If you want to also support larger images that customers can request on demand, simply upload the additional images according to the appropriate naming scheme and they will automatically be used where appropriate. The FAQs library on the Zen Cart support site at www.zen-cart.com address all these topics for your ongoing learning benefit.